# Custom Data Type: Rendering the name of the type and not the value of the property

Tags: c#-4.0

There is a custom data type for business object properties in one of my projects.  This custom type is a wrapper for the basic Data Types in .NET.

When I try and get the value from the property, the below is displayed if the syntax is:

```
company.Name 
Interfaces.Model.CustomType`1[System.String]
```

It is expecting:

```
company.Name.Value
```

I would like to avoid the need to use the .value; am I looking to overload an operation, or implicit/explicit methods?

Any help would be great.

Here is the general outline of the CustomType:

```
public class CustomType<t> 
{
    #region Implicit Casting

        /// <summary>
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static implicit operator t(CustomType<t> obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return new CustomType<t>().Value;
            return obj.Value;
        }
        /// <summary>
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static implicit operator CustomType<t>(t obj)
        {
            return new CustomType<t>(obj);
        }
        #endregion Implicit Casting


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The value.</value>      
        public t Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }

            set
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }


         /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public CustomType<t> setValue(t value)
        {
            try
            {
                Value = value;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {               

                throw new InvalidCastException("CustomType invalid property cast ", e.InnerException);
            }

            return this;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to override `ToString`.

```
public class CustomType<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString(); //I assume Value is of type T.
    }
}
```

I've done a certain amount of guessing here, perhaps you could show the code for your custom type and the all that's giving you the type.

Comment: This was all I needed. Makes sense after the fact; should have seen it. Added in a null check on the return and works great.